# why i cant add any plugin to my flutter project?

Tags: android, gradle, dart, flutter

i'm developing an app in flutter and when adding any plugin i get this error :

```
    * What went wrong:
    Could not resolve all files for configuration ':url_launcher:lintClassPath'.
    > Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.2.
      Searched in the following locations:
        - file:/E:/AndroidSDK/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.pom
        - file:/E:/AndroidSDK/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.jar
        - file:/E:/AndroidSDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.pom
        - file:/E:/AndroidSDK/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.jar
        - file:/E:/AndroidSDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.pom
        - file:/E:/AndroidSDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.jar
        - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.pom
        - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.jar
        - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.pom
- https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.jar
  Required by:
      project :url_launcher
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 47s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

My Pubspec Yaml Is Like This :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  shimmer: ^1.0.0

  http: ^0.12.0+1

  loadmore: ^1.0.2
```

and when i want to add url launcher plugin or any other plugin i got that error  .

thanks to any suggestion .

How Can i Solve This problem ?

Comment: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Can you run 
`flutter pub get -v`

Comment: @user1462442 I run this code , and my problem did'nt solve

Comment: I kinda want you to post the result. I am suspecting your project is pre 1.0 flutter?